# What is the difference between -, -X params and -XX params in JVM?

Tags: jvm

There are lots of parameters for JVM. Some start with `-`, such as `-server`, `-client`. Some start with `-X`, such as `-Xms`, `-Xmx`. Some start with `-XX`, such as `-XX:PermSize`, `-XX:UseParallelGC`.

Since these parameters are not duplicated, why start with so many different prefix? Why not just use `-`. My guess is there are some kind of standards for this. The `-XX` parameters are extension settings and not supported by all JVM impls. Is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, its the level of support.  The vanilla ("-") options are supported in future versions, and the X are not supported.  Further, the XX options are "not recommended for casual use".

For an example, see IBM's JVM documentation: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.user.aix64.60%2Fdiag%2Fappendixes%2Fcmdline%2Fcommands_jvm.html

Answer (score 13):

**These are three main categories of *Command-Line Argument*  options:**

- ***Standard options*** :Options that begin with - are  Standard options are expected to be accepted by all JVM implementations and are stable between releases (though they can be deprecated).
- ***Non-standard options*** :Options that begin with -X are non-standard (not guaranteed to be supported on all JVM implementations), and are subject to change without notice in subsequent releases of the Java SDK.
- ***Developer options*** :Options that begin with -XX are developer options and often have specific system requirements for correct operation and may require privileged access to system configuration parameters; they are not recommended for casual use. These options are also subject to change without notice.

[src](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html)

Answer (score 2):

- Options that begin with -X are non-standard (not guaranteed to be supported on all VM implementations), and are subject to change without notice in subsequent releases of the JDK.
- Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are subject to change without notice.

[Java Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Answer (score 1):

`java -help`:

```
-X     Displays information about non-standard options and exit
```

Comment: But wher’s the help for `-XX`?